# Where's the difference between [MyClass alloc] and [[self class] alloc]?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is there a good reason why I should not do something like this?
Example:

I have a class **MyClass**. In there I have this implementation:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    MyClass *copy = [[MyClass allocWithZone:zone] init];
    copy.someproperty = [[self.someproperty copy] autorelease];
    return copy;
}
```

Instead of that, I found a snippet that looks like this:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    MyClass *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    copy.someproperty = [[self.someproperty copy] autorelease];
    return copy;
}
```

The difference is, that the first one just uses the name if its own class humanly readable just as if it was any other class. And the second one asks self for what class that is. Does that make a difference, or are both totally okay to use in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you subclass `MyClass`, then the second example of `-copyWithZone:` returns an instance of the subclass. The first example doesn't, it returns an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: So inside a class when wanting to create an instance of that same class, one should always call [[self class] alloc] instead of [TheClass alloc]?

Comment: It depends on whether a subclass should be dealing with that method. In -copyWithZone: a subclass could call your method via super, do extra configuration then return the result. Using [self class] is therefore preferable.

Comment: a subclass doesn't necessarily need to call it via super. if the subclass doesn't have any extra variables of its own, it could just inherit it without any extra work

Comment: @user102008 yes, but the defensive approach is to assume that subclasses add ivars. They normally do.